# Proving $\frac{\cot^2x+1}{\cot^2x} = \sec^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to prove this identity switching between the trigonometric identities but I keep ending up nowhere and eventually get too many repeating identities.

> Prove they are equal.
>   $$ \frac{\cot^2x+1}{\cot^2x} = \sec^2x $$

Comment: Hint: just write everything in terms of $\sin,\cos$ and eliminate the denominators.

Answer (score 2):

we have $$\frac{\cot^2(x)+1}{\cot^2(x)}=\frac{\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+1}{\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}}{\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Comment: Well no wonder I couldn't figure it out. The table I have of identities doesn't have those identities in it. The ones were cot^2x = cos^2x / sin^2x.

Answer (score 2):

If the identities

$$\cot x={1\over\tan x}\qquad\text{and}\qquad1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$$

are already known to you, then

$${\cot^2x+1\over\cot^2x}=1+{1\over\cot^2x}=1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$$

Answer (score 1):

You would solve it with the identity $\cot^2x+1 = \csc^2x$, you substitute that, and then simplify the fraction.

$$\frac{\cot^2x+1}{\cot^2x}$$
$$=\frac{\csc^2x}{\cot^2x}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}{\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x*\sin^2x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cos^2x} = \sec^2x$$

Comment: If you put a backslash in front of all your trig functions, e.g. change "cot" to "\cot", your formulas will all look much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $$x + 1 = \frac{1}{x^{-1}} + 1 = \frac{x^{-1} + 1}{x^{-1}}.$$

Replace the $x$ by $\tan^2 x$, then $$\sec^2 x = \frac{\cot^2 x + 1}{\cot^2 x}.$$